# Nikon D3100 Making weird sounds while trying to take photo

Tags: lens, dslr, troubleshooting, nikon-d3100, sound

Whenever it try to take a photo on my nikon D3100 it keeps making weird motor sounds. I have dropped its lens once about 3 months ago but has been working fine until now. Here's a link to the sounds it makes: [Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-_iLQT7QRCYjBfReOzQ7RTZunODWMztK?usp=sharing). Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you have another lens that you could try with? That should indicate at least whether the problem is with the lens or the camera body.

Comment: Does it ever settle down & allow you to take the photo? Are you testing outdoors in daylight, with a clear subject? Is it OK set to manual? Does it focus manually?

Comment: @osullic I don't have another lens.

Comment: @Tetsujin yes it does settle when I go outdoors in bright sunlight. But that also usually takes time. Indoors, it rarely settles and that also after a long time. The lens is set to manual mode.

Comment: This is conflicting information. If the lens is set to manual, it should never try to autofocus. If set to auto, then indoors it could be that the lens is just slow, there's not enough light. Outdoors it should be pretty quick, assuming it has something it can find easily. What is the lens? The stock 18-55? I just dragged mine out of the cupboard & even indoors it focusses in under a second. I cannot hear the motor. This may suggest the drop damaged the mechanism. [Conversely I can clearly hear the motor on a Tamron I also own]

Comment: My comment was supposed to be a hint to _get_ another lens. You don't have to buy one - just find someone who has a Nikon camera too, or go to a camera shop and ask nicely to try a working lens on your camera.